# Using replace with select statement for a specific column in SQL oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, replace

Lets say I have a following table named INFO:

```
NAME   CITY                PROFESSION
A      New-Mexico          Software-Developer
B      Tampa               Software-Analyst
```

I only wish to replace the "-" in the PROFESSION column with a '/'. What should be the query to display ALL contents of the table INFO , with the above mentioned change?

I tried :

```
SELECT REPLACE(PROFESSION,'-','/') , * from INFO;
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have any other columns in your `SELECT` list, you can't use plain asterisk sign (`*`). You have to use table name or alias with it:

```
SELECT REPLACE(PROFESSION,'-','/') , info.* from INFO;
```

What you want, I guess, is:

```
SELECT name, city, REPLACE(PROFESSION,'-','/') AS profession FROM info;
```

Test:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  city VARCHAR2(20),
  profession VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO info VALUES ('A', 'New-Mexico', 'Software-Developer');
INSERT INTO info VALUES ('B', 'Tampa', 'Software-Analyst');

COMMIT;

SELECT name, city, REPLACE(PROFESSION,'-','/') AS profession FROM info;
```

Output:

```
NAME                 CITY                 PROFESSION         
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
A                    New-Mexico           Software/Developer   
B                    Tampa                Software/Analyst
```

[Oracle SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20d08/1)

[MySQL SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9ed6b/1)